# What does my Java professor mean by Partial Constructor?

Tags: java

My Professor asked for us to create the following for a object called JRectangle:

1. create a default constructor
2. create 2 member variables (Length , Width)
3. create a partial constructor
4. create a full constructor

The rest of the project i understand but the fact that i cannot find any sources that include partial constructor I am left here completely confused. Thanks for the help.

is this possibly what he means?

public class JRectangle
{

```
double Width ;
double Length;
//Default constructor
public JRectangle(){} 
//Full constructor
public JRectangle(double W )    
{
    Width = W;
}
//Partial constructor 
public JRectangle(double L, double W)
{
    Length = L;
    Width  = W;
}
//MUTATORS
public void SetWidth( double W)
{
    Width  = W;
}
public void SetLength( double L )
{
    Length = L;
}

public double GetWidth()
{
    return Width;
}

public double Area()
{
    return Width*Length;
}
public double Perimeter()
{
    return (2*Width)+(2*Length);
}
```

}

Comment: You'll have to ask your professor - it's not a widely used or official term. We could *guess*, but it really will only be a guess.

Comment: Never heard of this..

Comment: _Perhaps_ they mean to have a constructor that calls another constructor?

Comment: What your professor may asking for the constructor where you can create constructor with giving input variables less than the number of member variables and use the default values for rest of them.

Comment: Hope your prof is not talking about .NET's [Partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Your professor might mean something like

```
int length;
int width;
JRectangle()  // default
JRectangle(int l)  // partial:  sets length, but defaults width
JRectangle(int l, int w) //full constructor. to set width and length
```

Though its best to ask your professor.

Comment: I hope that this is what the professor meant. But as other comments suggest, ask the professor because this is not real terminology.

Comment: public class JRectangle
{
  
 double Width ;
 double Length;
 //Default constructor
    public JRectangle(){} 
    //Full constructor
    public JRectangle(double W ) 
    {
  Width = W;
 }
 //Partial constructor 
 public JRectangle(double L, double W)
 {
  Length = L;
  Width  = W;
 }
 //MUTATORS
 public void SetWidth( double W)
 {
  Width  = W;
 }
 public void SetLength( double L )
 {
  Length = L;
 }
 
 public double GetWidth()
 {
  return Width;
 }
 
 public double Area()
 {
  return Width*Length;
 }
 public double Perimeter()
 {
  return (2*Width)+(2*Length);
 }
}
Is this what he means?